# Pandas GroupBy and add count of unique values as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

#### Problem

I'm trying to group a Pandas DataFrame by columns `day` and `source`, and then count unique instances of a 3rd (`timestamp`) for each group (to find out how many hits each source got per day), but I get this error (full traceback below):
`TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

#### Attempts

My code is:

```
df['timestamp_count'] = df.groupby(["source", "day"]).agg({"timestamp": "nunique"})
```

And ideally I'd like to get a result like this (including the new column, `timestamp_count`:

```
day    source    timestamp                timestamp_count
1      facebook  2018-08-04 11:16:32.416  2
1      facebook  2019-01-03 10:25:38.216  2
1      twitter   2018-10-14 13:26:22.123  1
2      facebook  2019-01-30 12:16:32.416  1
```

When I run `df.describe()`, I see that `source` is an object but `day` is an integer. Could this be part of the problem? Having looked at other questions, it seems probable that it is along those lines, yet none of them seem to throw the same input/error combination.

Can anyone help a Python newbie? Many thanks!

#### Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-db5a002137ca> in <module>
----> 1 df['timestamp_count'] = (df.groupby["source", 
"day"]).agg({"timestamp": "nunique"})

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please provide the *FULL* traceback (which also includes the line that causes the error). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed, I have done so.

Comment: It's `df.groupby(["source", "day"])`, not `(df.groupby["day", 
"source"])`. You fixed the typo in your post but didn't realise it was in your code.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed now. @coldspeed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `transform` to broadcast the result:

```
df['timestamp_count'] = (
    df.groupby(["source", "day"])['timestamp'].transform('nunique'))
df

   day    source                timestamp  timestamp_count
0    1  facebook  2018-08-04 11:16:32.416                2
1    1  facebook  2019-01-03 10:25:38.216                2
2    1   twitter  2018-10-14 13:26:22.123                1
3    2  facebook  2019-01-30 12:16:32.416                1
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the new timestamp_count column as a datetime object, any tips for turning it into an integer?

Comment: @FPL `df.groupby(["source", "day"])['timestamp'].transform('nunique')` returns a column of integers. Please check once more.

Comment: I have checked and run everything again, and still getting datetimes :-( 
(df.info() returns "timestamp_count               143375 non-null datetime64[ns]")

Comment: @FPL What if you do `df['timestamp_count'] = df.groupby(["source", "day"])['timestamp'].transform('nunique').astype(int)`? Can you print `df['timestamp_count'].head().tolist()` for me?

Comment: That worked! Many thanks for your help! I wasn't sure where to add the function... still new to all this.